# Conditional occurrences of specific strings and relatively making a new data frame using R

Tags: r, dataframe, count, conditional-statements, find-occurrences

I have a big data frame with 4 columns and many rows (an example is attached).

```
#what I have
Arm <- c("5prime","3prime","5prime","CoMature","3prime","5prime","3prime","3prime")
Family <- c("LET-7","LET-7","LET-7","MIR-10","MIR-103","MIR-124","MIR-124","MIR-124")
Sequence <- c("ATCGGCA","ATGCTAC","ATCGGCA","ATCGTTT","TGAGGAG","TGATCAG","AATTCAG","AATTCAG")
Star_seq <- c("TTCAGGT","TATACTG","TTCAGGT","GAGATCA","CAAAAGC","CACATGC","AATATGC","AATATGC")
my_data_frame <- data.frame(Arm,Family,Sequence,Star_seq)
```

What I want to do is basically for each i in the Family column count the number of occurrences of '5prime', '3prime' or 'CoMature' in the Arm column. And then for the most frequent one ('5prime','3prime' or 'CoMature') take the third and fourth column. To sum up, I need to have a final file that shows the most frequent arm (in the first row) for each i in the Family column and their relative sequences in third and fourth columns.

```
#what I want as output
five_prime_counts <- c("2","0","0","1")
three_prime_counts <- c("1","0","1","2")
CoMature_counts <- c("0","1","0","0")
Arm_new <- c("5prime","CoMature","3prime","3prime")
Family_new <- c("LET-7","MIR-10","MIR-103","MIR-124")
Sequence_new <- c("ATCGGCA","ATCGTTT","TGAGGAG","AATTCAG")
Star_seq_new <- c("TTCAGGT","GAGATCA","CAAAAGC","AATATGC")
my_data_frame_new <- data.frame(five_prime_counts,three_prime_counts,CoMature_counts,Arm_new,Family_new,Sequence_new,Star_seq_new)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add a count variable for each `Family` and `Arm`, get the corresponding `Sequence`, `Star_seq` and `Arm` value for maximum count in each `Family` and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

my_data_frame %>%
  add_count(Family, Arm) %>%
  group_by(Family) %>%
  mutate(Sequence = Sequence[which.max(n)], 
         Star_seq =  Star_seq[which.max(n)], 
         Arm_new = Arm[which.max(n)]) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Arm, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))

#  Family  Sequence Star_seq Arm_new  `5prime` `3prime` CoMature
#  <fct>   <fct>    <fct>    <fct>       <int>    <int>    <int>
#1 LET-7   ATCGGCA  TTCAGGT  5prime          2        1        0
#2 MIR-10  ATCGTTT  GAGATCA  CoMature        0        0        1
#3 MIR-103 TGAGGAG  CAAAAGC  3prime          0        1        0
#4 MIR-124 AATTCAG  AATATGC  3prime          1        2        0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there is this error:   Error: 'pivot_wider' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyr'     and I dont have count columns as well

Comment: @MortezaAslanzadeh I think you need to update `tidyr` package. Do `install.packages('tidyr')` Or use `spread` instead of `pivot_wider` if you have an older version.

Comment: I spread instead of pivote_wider but this error poped up and again there is no columns for counts .......Error in tidyr::spread(., names_from = Arm, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) : 
  unused arguments (names_from = Arm, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
>

Comment: and this is the error when I install #tidyr......xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tidyr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tidyr’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tidyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyr’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: @MortezaAslanzadeh Use `my_data_frame %>%
  add_count(Family, Arm) %>%
  group_by(Family) %>%
  mutate(Sequence = Sequence[which.max(n)], 
         Star_seq =  Star_seq[which.max(n)], 
         Arm_new = Arm[which.max(n)]) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  tidyr::spread(Arm, n, fill = 0)`

Comment: maybe this will be usefull for someone else. the error was because I'm using mac and I typed this in terminal .....xcode-select --install..... and after installing the software I installed tidyr successfully

Comment: Yes but I have the counts in the console but when I do View(my_data_frame) it has four columns without counts.

Comment: Please assign the results `my_data_frame_new  <- my_data_frame %>% add_count(Family, Arm) %>% ...rest of the code....` and then check `my_data_frame_new`.

Comment: It solved. Thank you so much you have five stars from me :)

Comment: dear Ronak can I have my new_data_frame in this format?

Comment: five_prime_counts <- c("2","2","0","0","1","1")
 three_prime_counts <- c("1","1","0","1","2","2")
 CoMature_counts <- c("0","0","1","0","0","0")
 Arm_new <- c("5prime","5prime","CoMature","3prime","3prime","3prime")
 Family_new <- c("LET-7","LET-7","MIR-10","MIR-103","MIR-124","MIR-124")
 Sequence_new <- c("ATCGGCA","ATCGGCA","ATCGTTT","TGAGGAG","AATTCAG","AATTCAG")
 Star_seq_new <- c("TTCAGGT","TTCAGGT","GAGATCA","CAAAAGC","AATATGC","AATATGC")
 my_data_frame_new <- data.frame(five_prime_counts,three_prime_counts,CoMature_counts,Arm_new,Family_new,Sequence_new,Star_seq_new)

Comment: It is basically same analyses but just keeping every row that has a high count in the Arm column for every i in the Family. Because there are nucleotide variety so I dont want to loose them by keepin just a single row for every i in the Family column

Comment: Sorry, the code is not clear in the comments. Would you mind asking a new question with appropriate code and data?